# Maximum duration for Canada's short term visas?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens

I want to apply for a short stay visa for Canada. I see somewhere where they say short stay is 6 months valid up to 10 years.  As I am from Nigeria, what's the maximum duration for Canada's short term visas? 6 months or 10 years.

I found this information on the government site:

[image]

It seems to say I can't stay longer than 6 months. Is that correct?

Comment: surely this is a many-times duplicate ?

Answer (score 5):

The maximum duration of **the visa's validity** is ten years or until one month before the expiration of your passport, whichever is shorter.  The maximum duration of **each visit** is usually six months, but the passport must be valid for the entire duration of your visit.

From http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16, emphasis added:

> Multiple entry visa
>
> While valid, a multiple entry visa will let you travel to Canada **for six months at a time** as many times as you want. It will be valid **for up to 10 years or one month before your passport expires, whichever is shorter**. You must arrive in Canada on or before the expiry date on your visa.

Comment: Note that practically speaking it will almost always be shorter than 10 years since passports are issued for 10 years or less nowadays.

Comment: that's intriguing that it expires when the passport expires; normally with such visas you just take it along in the old passport with your new passports.

Comment: There are more countries that never give visa beyond the validity of the passport. And many people will not get the maximum length of visa when they apply the first time, but I am not sure about Canada.